# Manage Keyboard in Chat View

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

I have a controller like chat view, with one textfield and button and table view. I want to when user tap to textfield textfield go up and scroll to end of list. there is my code :

```
@objc func keyboardWillChangeFrame(_ notification: Notification) {

    let keyboardFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue

    print("*****************")
    print((keyboardFrame?.height)!)
     //emoji keyboard size is 258 
    if (keyboardFrame?.height)! == 258 {
      textBackViewBottom.constant =  52
    }
    else {
      textBackViewBottom.constant =  10
    }
    }

  @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    // Check for double invocation
    if _keyboardShown {
      return
    }
    _keyboardShown = true
    // Reducing size of table
    let baseView = self.view
    let keyboardFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    print("////////////////////")
    print((keyboardFrame?.height)!)
    let keyboardDuration = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).doubleValue
    let visibleRows = tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows
    var lastIndexPath : IndexPath? = nil
    if (visibleRows != nil) && visibleRows!.count > 0 {
      lastIndexPath = visibleRows![visibleRows!.count-1] as IndexPath
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration!, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
      baseView!.frame = CGRect(x: baseView!.frame.origin.x, y: baseView!.frame.origin.y, width: baseView!.frame.size.width, height: baseView!.frame.size.height - (keyboardFrame?.size.height)!)
    }, completion: {
      (finished: Bool) in
      if lastIndexPath != nil {
        // Scroll down the table so that the last
        // visible row remains visible
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: lastIndexPath!, at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom, animated: true)
      }
    })
  }

  @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {

    // Check for double invocation
    if !_keyboardShown {
      return
    }
    _keyboardShown = false
    // Expanding size of table
    //
    let baseView = self.view

    let keyboardFrame = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).cgRectValue
    let keyboardDuration = ((notification as NSNotification).userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]! as AnyObject).doubleValue
    UIView.animate(withDuration: keyboardDuration!, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
      baseView!.frame = CGRect(x: baseView!.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height + (keyboardFrame?.size.height)!)
    }, completion: nil)
  }
```

every thing work well with Iphone default keyboard, but when I'm using custom keyboard like Swiftkey my code is wrong and view broken.
How can get Update view when keyboard size and keyboard type change. 
thanks for reply.

Comment: what about IQKeyboard manager pod?

Comment: @SharadPaghadal I'm using IQKeyboard first but , in this case IQKeyboard move up controller and I loss controller top view element, and when I add one item in chat view Item doesn't show.